# Returning a variable after actionPerformed

Tags: java, actionlistener

I am trying to make a simple class where the user can change the value of the string test by clicking the button and then return the changed string.

```
public class TestTest
{
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel panelX;
    private String test;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestTest run = new TestTest();
        run.GUIinit();
        run.addButton();
        System.out.println(run.returnData());  // This returns null
    }

    // Method to return string value
    public String returnData()
    {
        return test;
    }

    // Method to set string value
    public void setData(String data)
    {
        test = data;
    }

    private void GUIinit()
    {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Text");
        mainFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        panelX = new JPanel();
        mainFrame.add(panelX);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Problematic part
    private void addButton()
    {
        JButton testButton = new JButton("Text");
        panelX.add(testButton);
        testButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                setData("STRING BLABLA");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I know that I am doing something horribly wrong but I cannot grasp what,
my only guess is that the code skips to the println part without waiting for the actionEvent.

**My question is:** Am I assigning a value to the string with the actionEvent when I click the button and if not, how could I do that? 
Could I implement some sort of delay or another class to get the result I want?

Comment: Only when you're actually pressing on your button is that your string *STRING BLABLA* is being assigned to your `test` field. Until then, your `test` is with value null.

Comment: So basically the println statement in main is happening before I click the button and thats why the value printed is still null? What would be the best way to get the changed value after clicking the button and then print it?

Comment: Exactly. When do you want to print it? After setting it you can do it whenever you want.

Comment: Well, I would like to print it in main after I change the value with the button.

Comment: The thing is that the assignment of the value to your `test` field is only done on the action event processing. I'd suggest on placing your `System.out.println(returnData());` after your `setData("STRING BLABLA");` inside `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Yeah, the printout works when I set it inside like you said, unfortunately I need to access the changed value outside the listener. The code I posted is just a part of a applet that I am working on. In short, I would like to work on the changed value after the actionEvent is fired.

Comment: Then, you should delegate that work, on the changed value, to another element and not doing it in your `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question - yes, you are assigning the value to the variable "test", but the main thread doesn't wait for you to click the button. That's why it prints null. You could make the main thread wait until the value is set, but that is a wrong way to use Swing. There are three kinds of threads in a Swing program:

- Initial thread, the thread that executes initial application code. In your case this is the thread that runs the main() method.
- Event dispatch thread (EDT), the thread where all event-handling code is executed. All program logic (unless it is time consuming) should be executed on this thread. In your case, whatever you need to do with the "test" variable, you should probably do it on this thread. Since action events are processed on this thread, you should do it in the actionPerformed() method of the listener.
- Worker threads. If the work is time consuming, you should create a new thread and do the work on it. Even so, you should start it from EDT (event dispatch thread), not the main (initial) thread.

You can read more here: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

If, however, for some unlikely reason you really need to access the "test" variable from the main (initial) thread, you can implement a waiting mechanism with Lock and Condition like so:

```
public class TestTest
{
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel panelX;
    private String test;

    private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static final Condition valueAssigned  = lock.newCondition();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        TestTest run = new TestTest();
        run.GUIinit();
        run.addButton();

        // Acquire the lock.
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (run.returnData() == null) {
                // Release the lock and wait for signal.
                valueAssigned.await();
            }
            // Once String value is set, print it.
            System.out.println(run.returnData());
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    // Method to return string value
    public String returnData()
    {
        return test;
    }

    // Method to set string value
    public void setData(String data)
    {
        test = data;
    }

    private void GUIinit()
    {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Text");
        mainFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        panelX = new JPanel();
        mainFrame.add(panelX);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Problematic part
    private void addButton()
    {
        JButton testButton = new JButton("Text");
        panelX.add(testButton);
        testButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                setData("STRING BLABLA");

                // Acquire the lock.
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    // Send a signal to all waiting threads.
                    valueAssigned.signalAll();
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Read more about Locks and Conditions here:
[Lock Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)

Comment: Thank you Vytas and @aribeiro for your explanations! Everything works as I intended with Locks and Condition, but it seems I have a lot more reading to do about Swing and threads in general.